# Using @variables MySQL in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get a iterator from MySQL (Sequelize Raw Query), using SET variables, as follows:

`SET @Variable:=0;
SELECT @Variable:=@Variable+1 AS AddNewColumn`

My specific code is:

`SET @i = 0;
    SELECT
    @i:=@i+1 AS iterator,
    COUNT(ci.id) totalCases,
...`

But throws the following error:

`'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'SELECT\n    @i:=@i+1 AS iterator,\n    COUNT(ci.id) totalCases,\n    SUM(b_p.amount\' at line 2',`

Any idea?

By the way, I'm using MySQL 5.7:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED 05/17/2019 14:12**

In my raw query I'm assign @rownum:=0 in FROM, targeting the table before declarating, as follow:

`FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) case_imports, case_imports ci`

And at beginning:

`SELECT (@rownum:=@rownum+1) AS id, 
    COUNT(ci.id) totalCases,`

Finally, ordering by id:

`ORDER BY id`

Comment: I tried running and it ran but returned 0 results. When I try to run the raw query in the MySQLWorkbench, it returns the data. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you follow the order (first the SELECT, then FROM)?

Answer (score 3):

I found you can also use variables in Sequelize by breaking each SQL statement, including the variable declaration, into a separate query:

```
await sequelize.query('SET @i = 0;');
const rows = await sequelize.query(
    'SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS iterator FROM someTable;',
    { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT },
);
```

Or if you'd like to use a transaction:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
    await sequelize.query('SET @rank = -1;', { transaction });
    const querySql = `
        UPDATE someTable
            SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
            WHERE groupId = :groupId
            ORDER BY totalPoints DESC, age ASC;`;
    await sequelize.query(querySql, {
        transaction,
        replacements: { groupId },
    });
});
```

This was tested in `sequelize@4.44.3`, and I'm unsure if it changes in later versions.